# Is this a new feature? Mentioning an user with @ becomes a link to their user ID.

Tags: support, user-accounts, hyperlinks, display-names

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4249018/818304) post, the user @ mentioned a user and that became a link to his user ID. Usually, when we do this, it is not the case.

Is it a new feature?

Comment: Nope it is not a new feature. It is just write with @ they have used hyperlink like this `[@Lac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/833003/lac)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As pointed out in the comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34093/is-this-a-new-feature-mentioning-an-user-with-becomes-a-link-to-their-user-id#comment157150_34093), this is not a new feature. The OP of the linked post has just used Markdown formatting to manually add a link to the profile of the user in question. You can see how this was done by navigating to the [revisions history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4249018/revisions) for that post, and then clicking on '[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/f2188772-84c3-4d31-8049-8b10c8ca79c8/view-source)':

```
Using  [@Lac][1]'s comment, we have ...

[...]

  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/833003/lac
```